# How to determine next available network interface name and ip range?

Tags: network-interface, tunneling, tap

I am working on an application which can create TUN/TAP interface on host machine. I can create such interfaces using:

```
sudo ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap
```

Now the thing is, `tap0` is hardcoded here. It should be dynamic.

When I create next tap device, it should be `tap1` and so on.

Now when I go ahead to give range to the device, I can manually do like this:

```
sudo ip addr add 172.16.0.1/24 dev tap0
```

Now when I create tap1, I don't want to overlap the ip.

Is there any easy way to manage these tap devices?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0;
while [ $i -ne 5 ]
do
  sudo ip tuntap add tap$i mode tap &>/dev/null
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
   echo "$i"
   exit 0
  fi
  i=$(($i+1))
done
exit 1
```

Tries tun0 to tun4, creates the first free interface and returns the number

Answer (score 0):

For next available tap device, you can use following function:

```bash
function nextTapDevice() {
    counter=-1
    while [ $? -eq 0 ]; do
        counter=$(($counter+1))
        ip link show tap$counter &> /dev/null 
    done

    echo tap$counter
}

nextTapDevice
```

It runs on same principle as @stony described, but it keeps running till `ip link show` throws an error. Which means no device named `tap$counter` is available. That device name will be next available device name.

---

For next available IP range, you first need to adhere to policy or IP range. Make sure this IP range does not collides with other application such as of Docker or so.

For my use case, I have decided to use `172.16.0.0/16`. I'll be allocating last octet to each VM (application I am working with). I can run 256 VMs.

I am going to reuse modified version of my `nextTapDevice` function written above. Instead of returning `tap$counter` in above function, I'm going to return just the counter.

Here is the rest of the code:

```bash
function nextTapDevice() {
    counter=-1
    while [ $? -eq 0 ]; do
        counter=$(($counter+1))
        ip link show tap$counter &> /dev/null 
    done

    echo $counter
}

# nextTapDevice

function nextIPRange() {
    for ((i=0; i<$(nextTapDevice);++i)); do
        output=$(ip -br addr show tap$i | awk '{print $3}')
    done
    echo $output | awk -F. '{ print $1"."$2"."$3+1"."$4 }'
}

nextIPRange
```

Drawback: The 3rd octet would keep incrementing even after 256. You might want to implement additional checks if your use case exceeds that point.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a FreeBSD solution, based on the assumption that tunN will use local IP 172.16.N.1 and remote IP 10.172.N.1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# what's the base name of the network interface?  NO SPACES!
devBase='tun'

# Maximum of N interfaces, numbered 0 .. N-1   NO HIGHER THAN 256!
N=256

# what's the printf spec of the tun's local address?  NO SPACES!
ipLocal='172.16.%d.1'

# what's the printf spec of the tun's remote address?  NO SPACES!
ipRemote='10.172.%d.1'

nextTun() {
# $1 is the device base name

  result="$(jot -w "${1}%d" $N 0 | grep -vxFf <(ifconfig -l | grep -ow "${1}[0-9]\+") | head -1)"
  if [[ -n "$result" ]]
  then
    printf '%s\n' "$result"
  else
    exit $?
  fi
}

if tun="$(nextTun $devBase)"
then
        devN=${tun#$devBase}
        printf 'Creating %s ...\n' "$tun"
        ipl=$(printf $ipLocal  $devN)
        ipr=$(printf $ipRemote $devN)
        ifcfg="$(printf 'sudo ifconfig %s create %s %s' "$tun" $ipl $ipr )"
        sudo $ifcfg || {
                printf '"%s" failed.\n' $tun
                exit 2
        }
else
        printf 'No %s devices available.\n' "$devBase"
        exit 1
fi
```

This declares a function `nextTun` which accepts a base interface name, such as `tun`.  It quickly `jot`s down a list of the `N` possible `tun` devices, removes any `tun` devices already in use, and takes the first (lowest) `tun` device that is available.  If no `tun` device is available, the function returns no result, and a non-zero exit code.

The main code tests for a successful result from `nextTun`.  If found, then it constructs the necessary `ifconfig` syntax to create the `tun` device number `devN` with the appropriate local and remote IPs.  Once the syntax is built, it's passed to `sudo` to execute.  If `nextTun` indicates a failure to allocate an available `tun` device, the code indicates that no more devices are available, and returns a non-zero exit code.